# Must an onto isometry map 'corner' point of a square to another 'corner' point of a square?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, isometry

Suppose that $T:(\mathbf{R}^2, \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \rightarrow (\mathbf{R}^2, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is an onto linear isometry, which leads it to bijective isometry with isometry inverse.

The norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is defined as 
$$\|(a,b)\|_{\infty} = \max\{ |a|,|b|\}.$$
Recall that a unit ball with the above norm is a square centered at origin with unit length.

We assume that both domain of codomain of $T$ do not contain $\ell^{\infty}(2).$

For every $(a,b) \in \mathbf{R}^2,$ denote 
$$T(a,b) = (c,d)$$

> Question: For all $(a,b) \in \mathbf{R}^2$ with $|a| = |b| =1$, can we have $|c| = |d| = 1$ where $T(a,b) = (c,d)$?

In some sense, I am asking if I am given a 'corner' point on a square centered at origin with length $1,$ must the point be mapped to another 'corner' point of a square centered at origin with length $1$ under an onto isometry.

Comment: I assume the $\|a\|, \|b\|, \|c\|, \|d\|$ are absolute values?

Comment: If so, then it doesn't hold if $T$ is a translation.

Comment: But translation may not preserve max norm. For example, if the vector $(0.1)$ is translated upwards by $2$ units, then the new vector $(1,3)$ has max norm $3.$

Comment: By the way, may I know why the downvote?

Comment: Are you referring to a linear isometry? One that fixes $(0, 0)$?

Comment: It wasn't me. Have an up vote.

Comment: @TheoBendit: yes, sorry I forgot to mention linearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear isometry $T$ preserves extreme points of the unit ball, i.e. $p$ is an extreme point of the unit ball if and only if $T(p)$ is one. Since the extreme points of the unit square are its corners, indeed a linear isometry must map corners of the unit square to corners of the unit square.

Comment: Oops, I forgot such result. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: By the way, can you point me to a source such that the proof is given?

Comment: I don't know where a proof is in the literature, it should be in many books on functional analysis. If $x = \frac{1}{2}(y+z)$ with $y\neq z$ and $\lVert y\rVert,\,\lVert z\rVert \leqslant 1$, then $T(x) = \frac{1}{2}(T(y) + T(z))$. If $T$ is a linear isometry, we have $T(y) \neq T(z)$ and $\lVert T(y)\rVert,\,\lVert T(z)\rVert \leqslant 1$. So if $x$ is _not_ an extreme point of the unit ball, then $T(x)$ is _not_ an extreme point of the unit ball.

Comment: Based on your proof. it seems that any linear isometry will preserve extreme points of a unit ball regardless of domain of the linear isometry. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter whether we're in a finite-dimensional space or not, or whether the spaces are complete or not. If $E,F$ are normed spaces, and $T \colon E \to F$ a (bijective) linear isometry, then $T$ maps the extreme points of the unit ball of $E$, and only those, to extreme points of the unit ball of $F$.

Comment: In your proof, you said that if $x = \frac{1}{2}(y+z)$ with $y \neq z$ and $\|y\|, \|z\| \leq 1,$ then $T(x) = \frac{1}{2}(T(y) + T(z)).$ Do we assume $T$ is linear when proving the equatity?

Comment: Yes, we need $T\bigl(\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\bigr) = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(T(y) + T(z)\bigr)$.

Comment: Thanks. Final question, how do we identify whether a point in a direct sum of two Banach spaces is an extreme point? For example, if $A$ and $B$ are Banach spaces with $A \oplus_{\infty}B$ with max norm, how to identify whether $(a,b) \in A \oplus_{\infty}B$ is an extreme point of a unit ball? Is it those points with $\|a\| = \|b\| = 1?$

Comment: With $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_{A\oplus B} = \max \{ \lVert x\rVert_A,\, \lVert y\rVert_B\}$, the extreme points of the unit ball of the sum are the points whose first component is an extreme point of the unit ball of $A$, and whose second component is an extreme point of the unit ball of $B$. Unless the unit balls of $A$ and $B$ are _strictly_ convex, there will be points with $\lVert x\rVert_A = \lVert y\rVert_B = 1$ that are not extreme points of the unit ball of $A\oplus B$.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I started writing this before saying I could assume linearity, but of course, it should hold for any isometry.

To answer what I think is the spirit of your question, yes, a surjective isometry from $(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ must map spheres to spheres **and** preserve their corners.

To see this, look at the metric line segment from the centre of the sphere out to the points on the sphere. In fact, I think it helps just to look at the set,

$$M(x, y) = \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x - z\| = \|z - y\| = \frac{\|x - y\|}{2}\right\rbrace.$$

Looking at it geometrically, it shouldn't be difficult to see that $M(x, y)$ is a singleton if and only if $x$ is on the corner of a sphere centred at $y$ (and vice-versa, of course). It's also easy to see, from the definition of isometry, that,
$$T(M(x, y)) = M(T(x), T(y)),$$
so $M(x, y)$ is a singleton if and only if $M(T(x), T(y))$ is a singleton. Thus, the "corner" relation is preserved.